# Python compilation error: "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform"

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gcc

This error message is not unknown, I have already reinstalled many packages, but so far not yet found a solution.

I get the following error from the command `pip install cryptography`

```
/usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:849:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."

#error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."

^
```

At the end of a long traceback it says:

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xXOpFq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

python-dev, python2.7-dev and python3-dev exist.

Comment: Please use a meaningful title. Yours says (translated from the gobbledygook) "There is a compilation error".

Comment: On the question itself, you need to trace where `LONG_BIT` and `SIZEOF_LONG` are defined. Should be fascinating. For a 64-bit system `LONG_BIT` should be 64 and `SIZEOF_LONG` and  `sizeof(long)` should be 8. `LONG_BIT` should depend on `LONG_MAX` in `limits.h` and and `SIZEOF_LONG` should be defined in `pyconfig.h`.

Comment: "python3-dev exist" : Not relevant unless the `pip3` command is used. ... Your OS is unknown. Could be Ubuntu 15.10 ? Cannot be Debian 8 : `cryptography` is installed already with `python-all-dev`. ... Just ran a `pip install cryptography` install test with five different OS's : No issues at all . ...

Comment: In /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h is defined `SIZEOF_LONG 4`. But in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h is defined `SIZEOF_LONG 8`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the right bits-installed for python.
In my case I installed anaconda python 32-bit on my 64-bit centOs which caused the issue. Installing the right bit version for Python fixed it.