# How to fix an unknown error when cross compiling my QT application to raspberry-pi3

Tags: c++, python-2.7, qt, raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling

my program (QT/C++)is using a python module to download some video from google drive, it's work very well but I couldn't cross compile it for raspberry pi3. 
I am new in QT Cross Compile for raspberry and I couldn't find a solution for this error in any place :

```
 #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
 ^
In file included from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/os_defines.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/c++config.h:426,
                 from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/cstddef:41,
                 from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/qt5pi/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:45,
                 from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/qt5pi/include/QtCore/qtimer.h:43,
                 from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/qt5pi/include/QtCore/QTimer:1,
                 from DigitalSignal.h:5,
                 from DigitalSignal.cpp:1:
/opt/qtrpi/raspbian/sysroot/usr/include/./features.h:230:0: note: ceci est l'emplacement d’une précédente définition
 # define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
 ^
In file included from lib/python2.7/Include/Python.h:8:0,
                 from DigitalSignal.cpp:15:
lib/python2.7/Include/pyconfig.h:1242:0: warning: « _XOPEN_SOURCE » redéfini [enabled by default]
 #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
 ^
In file included from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/os_defines.h:39:0,
                 from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/c++config.h:426,
                 from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/cstddef:41,
                 from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/qt5pi/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:45,
                 from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/qt5pi/include/QtCore/qtimer.h:43,
                 from /opt/qtrpi/raspi/qt5pi/include/QtCore/QTimer:1,
                 from DigitalSignal.h:5,
                 from DigitalSignal.cpp:1:
/opt/qtrpi/raspbian/sysroot/usr/include/./features.h:162:0: note: ceci est l'emplacement d’une précédente définition
 # define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
 ^
In file included from lib/python2.7/Include/Python.h:61:0,
                 from DigitalSignal.cpp:15:
lib/python2.7/Include/pyport.h:895:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  ^
Makefile:1145: recipe for target 'DigitalSignal.o' failed
make: *** [DigitalSignal.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python compilation error: "LONG\_BIT definition appears wrong for platform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745187/python-compilation-error-long-bit-definition-appears-wrong-for-platform)

Comment: no it's not the same, I am trying to cross compile a QT program (that  is using python module ) for raspberry

Comment: btw, I am using this link to cross compile : https://github.com/neuronalmotion/qtrpi

Comment: Begs the question: Which python lib is being used here? Wild guess, but it's probably using python libs of the build platform, not RasPi's. And that in turn is pulling in system headers instead of the stuff in `raspbian/sysroot`. I think you'll need to somehow force python to use the right includes... but that's more speculation.

Comment: I am trying to understand how the cross compile work . maybe I find something . 
so first of all when I am excute "qmake-qtrpi" commande that means that I am using all the library available in "/opt/qtrpi" .
so if I am using "#include <python>" in my QT code . that means I need necessary the same library in /opt/qtrpi like that way , qtrpi will find what he need . so my question is how can i find where qmake-qtrpi is loking for library that he need ??

Comment: for using python in QT, i needed to add two files. first one "lib" that  contains python2.7 and all the include for python .the second one is "module-python"
https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/2.7 . thos two file are now in the folder of my project and that way the project can find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on the solution of this problem [Python compilation error: "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745187/python-compilation-error-long-bit-definition-appears-wrong-for-platform) .I changed in **lib/python2.7/Include/pyconfig.h** this line `#define SIZEOF_LONG 8`  bye this line `#define SIZEOF_LONG 4` (explanation : '4' for 32 bits and '8' for 64 bits ).

but now I have a new error that i does't understand :::

```
t/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Xml -lQt5Core -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/qtrpi/raspbian/sysroot/opt/vc/lib -lGLESv2 -lpthread 
/home/Documents/project/digitalsignage/lib/python2.7//libpython2.7.a : erreur lors de l'ajout de symboles : Format de fichier non reconnu
collect2: error: ld a retourné le statut de sortie 1
Makefile:170: recipe for target 'DigitalSignal' failed
make: *** [DigitalSignal] Error 1
```

can anyone what is the meaning of this error ???