# "libpython2.7.a" format not recognized when cross compiling a project for raspberry pi3

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, python-requests, cross-compiling

my program (QT/C++) is using a python module to download some video from google drive, it's work very well but I couldn't cross compile it for raspberry pi3.this is was my first error  [How to fix an unknown error when cross compiling my QT application to raspberry-pi3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511331/how-to-fix-an-unknown-error-when-cross-compiling-my-qt-application-to-raspberry) . After fixing this error, I have now a new error that I  don't know what it's mean :

here is the error :

```
/home/Documents/project/digitalsignage/lib/python2.7/ -lpython2.7 -ldl -lutil -L/opt/qtrpi/raspi/qt5pi/lib -lQt5Quick -L/opt/qtrpi/raspbian/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Xml -lQt5Core -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/qtrpi/raspbian/sysroot/opt/vc/lib -lGLESv2 -lpthread 
/home/Documents/project/digitalsignage/lib/python2.7//libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:170: recipe for target 'DigitalSignal' failed
make: *** [DigitalSignal] Error 1
```

and here is the line 170 of the Makefile :

```
####### Build rules

$(TARGET): /home/Documents/project/digitalsignage/lib/python2.7/libpython2.7.a $(OBJECTS)  
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)
```

if any one know if i need to change some thing in the Makefile please help me ??

Comment: the problem is when I cross compile my project, the compiler doesn't understand the format of project/lib/python2.7/libpython.2.7.a  so I think that I need to cross compile  python2.7.a for raspberry pi3

Comment: So you have an answer... I guess you can also download a prenuolt version somewhere but cross compiling your own is definitely an option.

Comment: I don't need to cross-compile the python module but cross compiling the QT application (that include the initializing of the module python ) causes the compiling of the python module. For three days I am trying to find a way to override this but there is nothing

Comment: and also I couldn't find a prenuolt version (that work with raspberry )where the cross compiling understand the format of the module

Comment: Sorry I mean prebuilt version. Phone keyboard makes strange things.

Comment: If you don't need the python module you can try to remove it from your Qt project, but your question is not about that.

Comment: I think that I found an easy way to override this problem. I will just build the QT for raspberry and I will compile my project in the raspberry. And I am working at the same time on a solution for this error .